# File_put_contents zero

Tags: php, zero, file-put-contents

i want to use this code :
`echo file_put_contents('any.txt', 0);`
result will be 0!
I know that i can put zero in quotation but what about $_GET ?
Like this :
`echo file_put_contents('any.txt', $_GET['GetZero']);`
Result can't be **1** while we send **0** with **GetZero** parameter

**maybe 0 can not be send with any way :|**

How can do that?

Comment: `echo file_put_contents('any.txt', 0);` returns `1` (one byte is written), with a created file `any.txt` that contains exactly the character `0`, as expected

Answer (score 1):

the function `file_put_contents` returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or false on failure.

so if you will check your file is written use this:

```
$write = file_put_contents('any.txt', $_GET['GetZero']);
if($write!==false){
 echo "success";
}else{
 echo "fail";
}
```